# Fast access to sums of pairwise ops

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Given a vector of numbers `v`, I can access sums of sections of this vector by using cumulative sums, i.e., instead of `O(n)`

```py
v = [1,2,3,4,5]
def sum_v(i,j):
    return sum(v[i:j])
```

I can do `O(1)`

```
import itertools
v = [1,2,3,4,5]
cache = [0]+list(itertools.accumulate(v))
def sum_v(i,j):
    return cache[j] - cache[i]
```

Now, I need something similar but for `pairwise` instead of `sum_v`:

```
def pairwise(i,j):
    ret = 0
    for p in range(i,j):
        for q in range(p+1,j):
            ret += f(v(p),v(q))
    return ret
```

where `f` is, *preferably*, something *relatively* arbitrary (e.g., `*` or `^` or ...). However, something working for just product or just XOR would be good too.

**PS1**. I am looking for a speed-up in terms of [`O`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), not generic [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) such as [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache).

**PS2**. The question is about *algorithms*, not *implementations*, and is thus *language-agnostic*. I tagged it `python` only because my examples are in python.

**PS3**. Obviously, one can precompute all values of `pairwise`, so the solution should be `o(n^2)` both in time and space (preferably linear).

Comment: I don't think you can do better than O(N^2) here, since there are N^2 values to be considered. Any optimisation that can be done would be related to the properties of the operator (eg: bit manipulation if the operation is XOR, etc)

Comment: @AbhinavMathur: thanks, what would you do for, say, xor? (`f=^`)

Comment: Is numpy an option?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: I am looking for an _algorithm_, not its _implementation_; if `numpy` implements something, I can handle it. **However**, the issue is speedup in terms of `O`, not in terms of rewriting in `C`.

Comment: Numpy uses SIMD operations to get the speedup it does, which is not possible AFAIK in vanilla python. So your algorithm would still be `O(whatever)`, but because more data is being processed parallelly, the job runs faster.

Comment: @sds would O(N) be good enough?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur: oh yes! Considering that `pairwise` is `O(N^2)` as is...

Comment: @sds Okay, added as an answer

Comment: I suggest not restricting your question to O(n) precomputation time and space - there are some interesting data structures such as [segment trees](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html) which use O(n log n) space for lookups in O(log n) time, which is still better than the naive approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For binary operations such as `or, and, xor`, an `O(N)` algorithm is possible.
Let's consider XOR for this example, but this can be easily modified for OR/AND as well.
The most important thing to note here is, the result of a binary operator on bit `x` of two numbers will not affect the result for bit `y`. (You can easily see that by trying something like `010 ^ 011 = 001`. So we first count the contribution made by the leftmost bits of all numbers to the final sum, then the next least significant bit, and so on. Here's a simple algo/pseudocode for that:

1. Construct a simple table `dp`, where `dp[i][j] = count of numbers in range [i,n) with jth bit set`

```
l = [5,3,1,7,8]
n = len(l)
ans = 0

max_binary_length = max(log2(i) for i in l)+1  #maximum number of bits we need to check

for j in range(max_binary_length):
    # we check the jth bits of all numbers here
    for i in range(0,n):
        # we need sum((l[i]^l[j]) for j in range (i+1,n))
        current = l[i]
        if jth bit of current == 0:
            # since 0^1 = 1, we need count of numbers with jth bit 1
            count = dp[i+1][j]
        else:
            # we need count of numbers with jth bit 0
            count = (n-i)-dp[i+1][j] 
            # the indexing could be slightly off, you can check that once
        ans += count * (2^j)
        # since we're checking the jth bit, it will have a value of 2^j when set
print(ans)
```

In most cases, for integers, number of bits <= 32. So this should have a complexity of `O(N*log2(max(A[i])))` == `O(N*32)` == `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you can always precompute *every* possible output in Θ(n²) space and then answer queries in Θ(1) by just looking it up in the precomputed table. Everything else is a trade-off depending on the cost of precomputation time, space, and actual computation time; the interesting question is what can be done with o(n²) space, i.e. sub-quadratic. This will generally depend on the application, and on properties of the binary operation `f`.

In the particular case where `f` is `*`, we can get Θ(1) lookups with only Θ(n) space: we'll take advantage that the sum for pairs where `p < q` equals the sum of all pairs, minus the sum of pairs where `p = q`, divided by 2 to account for the pairs where `p > q`.

```py
# input data
v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = len(v)

# precomputation
partial_sums = [0] * (n + 1)
partial_sums_squares = [0] * (n + 1)
for i, x in enumerate(v):
    partial_sums[i + 1] = partial_sums[i] + x
    partial_sums_squares[i + 1] = partial_sums_squares[i] + x * x

# query response
def pairwise(i, j):
    s = partial_sums[j] - partial_sums[i]
    s2 = partial_sums_squares[j] - partial_sums_squares[i]
    return (s * s - s2) / 2
```

More generally, this works whenever `f` is commutative and distributes over the accumulator operation (`+` in this case). I wrote the example here without itertools, so that it is more easily translatable to other languages, since the question is meant to be language-agnostic.